# Writing MATLAB arrays in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, matlab

The MATLAB code samples part of `background` of an grayscale image by creating a cell array that is `backgroundSample{1}`, `backgroundSample{2}`, ... , `backgroundSample{9}`. Here `halfRows` and `halfCols` is the half size of the image.

Since `backgroundSample` is an array that contains nine 2-D matrices. It confused me that how to write this code in C/C++. Can I get the elements of `backgroundSample{i}` using something like `backgroundSample[i].elements[m][n]`?

**MATLAB code:**

```
offset = [-60, -20, 20, 60];  
for i = 1: 1: 3                             
    for j = 1: 1: 3
        backgroundSample{(i - 1) * 3 + j} = 
        background(halfRows + offset(i): halfRows + offset(i + 1), ...
                   halfCols + offset(j): halfCols + offset(j + 1));
    end;
end;
```

**EDIT:**
As we can assign a matrix simply by `A = B` in MATLAB. For an example, `backgroundSample{1} = background(60: 100, 60: 100)` in my question and this assignment is in the loops of i: 1→3 and j: 1→3. However, when assigning a matrix in C/C++, it should assign every element one by one. Maybe like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for(int j = 0; n < 3; j++)
        // to get every elements
        for(int m = 0 ...)
            for(int n = 0 ...)
                // not sure whether there is such usage of "->" in array
                backgroundSample[(i - 1) * 3 + j]->elements[m][n] =  background[i iteration][j iteration]
```

So there are conflicts between indices of matrix `backgroundSample[m][n]` and `background[i][j]`. How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Are you trying to write a MEX file, or just an equivalent C/C++ program?

Comment: @EitanT I'm writing an equivalent C/C++ program

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? Declare an array of nine pointers to 2-D matrices and allocate sufficient memory for each matrix. Accessing an element in the _i_-th  matrix would probably look something like `backgroundSample[i]->elements[j][k]`

Comment: OR, you could create your own Matrix class, that could do all that a Matlab matrix can do. All this nested for loops stuff would be encapsulated by your class (e.g. in a GetElement function).

Comment: @EitanT I added more description of the question, please give an example of pointers to matrices you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to implement what you're describing is to declare a multidimensional array:

```
int backgroundSample[9][3][3];
```

where the dimensions of each 2-D matrix is assumed to be 3×3. To access the (*m*, *n*) element in the *k*-th matrix, you write `backgroundSample[k][m][n]`, *e.g*:

```
for (int m = 0; m < 3; ++m)
{
    for(int n = 0; n < 3; ++n)
    {
       backgroundSample[(i - 1) * 3 + j][m][n] = background[i][j];
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if each sample in this array stores more information, you can declare a structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    int elements[3][3];

    // More fields...
} TSample;
```

and then create an array of these:

```
TSample backgroundSample[9];
```

To access an element you would write `backgroundSample[k].elements[m][n]`.

There's also the possibility of allocating the memory dynamically (during runtime, meaning that you don't know how much of these structures you have in advance):

```
TSample* backgroundSample;
```

In C++ the actual process of memory allocation would look like this:

```
backgroundSample = new TSample[9];
```

Accessing an element would be done by writing `backgroundSample[k]->elements[m][n]`. Notice the array operator `->` which accesses the field `elements` by dereferencing the pointer `backgroundSample[k]`.

Note: each call to `new` needs to be accompanied by a matching call to `delete` when done in order to release the memory, *i.e*:

```
delete[] backgroundSample;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, but there may exist a mistake: your code `backgroundSample[(i - 1) * 3 + j][m][n] = background[i][j];` should be also in the loop of i and j, right? So in this way `backgroundSample[0][m][n]` will be assigned the same value because `background[i][j]` won't change until it jumps out of loop m & n.

Comment: Yes, it's just an example of usage. It is assumed to be inside a nested for loop that iterates `i` and `j`, just like it is assumed that array `background` is defined somewhere else. Obviously, you should modify this according to your need.